# SQL Server IN/OR accuracy/context

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following columns in my_table:

customer_id, transaction_date, shop name, transaction_id

If I write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) as transaction_count
FROM my_table
WHERE shop_name = 'A'
OR shop_name = 'B'
AND transaction_date > 'yyyy-mm-dd'
AND COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) > 2
```

I get 100 records

If I write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) as transaction_count
FROM my_table
WHERE shop_name IN ('A','B')
AND transaction_date > 'yyyy-mm-dd'
AND COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) > 2
```

I get 50 records

Why the difference in records in this context? Is IN (for shop_name) more accurate than OR or vice versa?

Thank you.

Comment: The query is missing the `GROUP BY` clause or it is not MS SQL Server(it will end up with an error)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same result with `the OR condition` like the `IN operator` then you need to put your `OR condition` within bracket -

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) as transaction_count
FROM my_table
WHERE (shop_name = 'A'
OR shop_name = 'B')
AND transaction_date > 'yyyy-mm-dd'
AND COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) > 2
```

Comment: Thank you @Fahmi, but what is it doing when I don't add the brackets, it seems the results are still accurate somehow?

Comment: @nleiserowitz, it should be the same result - it'll vary. Fortunately, you are getting in this case - but it won't be same for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) as transaction_count
FROM my_table
WHERE shop_name = 'A'
OR shop_name = 'B'
AND transaction_date > 'yyyy-mm-dd'
AND COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) > 2
```

is equivalent of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) as transaction_count
FROM my_table
WHERE shop_name = 'A'
OR (shop_name = 'B'
    AND transaction_date > 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) > 2)
```

Here additional conditions affects only shop_name = 'B'